# Download and upload images with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, image

In my web application, I need to be able to allow users to upload and download their images. How can this be don in ASP.net?

I want to user to be able to sign in (I already have that done) and be able to upload images to their account. Later on, I want them to be able to download them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are of a reasonable size, (e.g. less than a few MB), you can do this with a <input type=file> tag. Set the encoding of your form tag to multipart/form-data and implement some code-behind to get a hold of the file.

See the ASP.Net videos ([Part 1](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-255.aspx)) and ([Part 2](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-252.aspx)) for a detailed example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="upImage" Width="575px" CssClass="txt-Normal"></asp:FileUpload>
```

Here is my method to save them to a location on the site.

```
string completeFilePath = this.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUploadPath"];

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(completeFilePath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(completeFilePath);
}

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(completeFilePath + this.upImage.FileName))
{
    this.upImage.SaveAs(completeFilePath + this.upImage.FileName);
}

imageUrl = string.Format("~{0}{1}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUploadPath"], this.upImage.FileName);
```