# ASP.net Image Upload and rename it with autogenerated Id of Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Can u tell me how to upload a image through ASP.net web forms.
I want to upload the image and rename it to the autogenerated ID returned by Database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download and upload images with ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622537/download-and-upload-images-with-asp-net)

Comment: There are TONS of documented solutions for uploading files with ASP.NET web forms, including right here on SO.  Do some research first.  Search engines are your friends.

Comment: @kon; You are right. there is much more material available to handle this scenario. Lets try to help him if he have some problem in implementation. As we are here to help each other.

Comment: There's a difference between helping with implementation and hand-feeding.  I see no implementation attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming in my answer, that you were successfully able to insert the record and get the inserted ID:

```
Int32 RecentGenerateID = 34;//Assign ID that you are getting from the DB

if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FolderName/" + RecentGenerateID.ToString() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName));
}
```

Comment: My FileUpload1.HasFile is always returning false.Should i make any special configurations settings in Web.config, or it may be some other reason?